# Error in ./configure in solaris 11

Tags: solaris, bind, configure

Okay i am trying to install BIND on solaris 11.

Upon downloading the tar file using wget, then i used extract it out.

After which, when i enter the command :

```
./configure
```

i face the following error

```
checking <<some stuff>>
..
..
..
checking <<some stuff>>
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in '/home/user/user/downloads/bind9.8.2
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.
```

so i used --host in my option, but i cant get it to work,
For example, i entered the below command :

```
 ./configure --host=ulinux-uclibc
```

I received an error saying

```
   checking host system type... Invalid configuration 'ulinux-uclibc': machine 'ulinux' not recognized
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you run even _simple_ programs? Try this: `echo "int main(int arch, char* argv[]) { return 0; }" > foo.c ; cc foo.c ; ./a.out`

Comment: Chances are you have no C compiler installed on this Solaris machine.  Also, why are you specifying --host=ulinux-uclibc if it's a Solaris machine?

Comment: Check `config.log` for details of what test program it tried to build, what command it tried to use to build it, and what the exact errors were from the compiler/linker/loader/runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install the bind package from your configured solaris publisher?

```
# pkg install network/dns/bind service/network/dns/bind
```

should get you exactly what you need. That will get you ISC Bind v9.6.3 if you use `pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release` publisher.